# Program is writing fine, but not reading

Tags: c++

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i = 20;

    fstream fs("someFile.dat", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::in);
    if(!fs)
    {
        cout << "FILE COULD NOT BE OPENED" << endl;
    }

    fs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i),sizeof(int));
    i = 0;
    fs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i),sizeof(int));
    cout << i << endl;  // shows 0
}
```

The 'i' in cout at the last should display 20 but it shows 0.

Comment: Step 1: Check if the read/write operations succeeded. I'm going to guess and say that the read fails (see Alexander's answer)

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After writing to the file, you are at the end of the file.

You can figure this out using [tellg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/), or "tell get":

```
std::cout << "Position in file is: " << fs.tellg() << std::endl;
```

This will tell you the byte offset you are within the file, from the start of the file. You need to seek the appropriate position in the file first, before you can read bytes from the file. To do so, we can use [seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/istream/seekg/), or "seek get".

```
fs.seekg(0);
```

This seeks the beginning of the file (byte offset of 0 from the start of the file), so you should be able to read from the file correctly.

For your example, `seekg` and `seekp` should be identical, as are `tellg` and `tellp`, but you should ideally use the member functions ending in "g"  (for "get") for input streams, and the functions ending in "p" (for "put") for output streams.

**EDIT**

A good point was raised in the comments by @Borgleader, for more complicated examples, you may not know if a read failed. To do so, you can check the fail bit:

```
if (fs.fail()) {   
    // you can check more specific error codes with std::ios_base::iostate
    // fs.fail() will evaluate to 0 if no error, or false, otherwise it has an error
    std::cout << "Failed to read from file" << std::endl;
}
```

**UPDATE**

To analyze iostate flags, you can use the fstream member functions `good`, `eof`, `fail`, `bad`. A quick example checking the iostate of an fstream for the original example follows:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 20;
    std::fstream fs("someFile.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    fs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i), sizeof(int));
    i = 0;
    fs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i), sizeof(int));
    // you can check other settings via the ios::fail() member function
    if (fs.good()) {            // checks goodbit
        std::cout << "File is normal, no errors\n";
    }
    if (fs.eof()) {            // checks end of file
        std::cout << "End of file\n";
    }
    if (fs.fail()) {            // checks failbit or badbit
        std::cout << "Failed to read, failbit\n";
    }
    if (fs.bad()) {             // checks the badbit
        std::cout << "Failed to read, badbit\n";
    }
}
```

This, when run produces the following output:

```
End of file
Failed to read, failbit
```

Overall, often checking if the read fails is sufficient, unless you need to further refine your logic.

Comment: This just shows how terrible the naming is of those functions.

Comment: O man thanks a lot it worked. I thought only **put file position pointer** offsets when we write to a file. I didn't know **get file position pointer** offsets as well. Thanks a lot man, it was my first question on stackoverflow, I wasn't expecting the right answer.

Comment: Of course @AhmadJamalMughal. If my answer worked, and it is the best answer available, please mark the answer as correct so the question can be closed.

Comment: Plus, can you please suggest me some resource to learn state bits, I've read lot about them but still they confuse me.

Comment: @AhmadJamalMughal, you can read about the flags here and how to check them:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdstate/

However, they can be somewhat confusing (still). I'll update my answer.